# How to add one folder on different branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I am trying to add one folder in different branch. In my master branch I have all the folders. I created new branch using:

```
git branch practice
git checkout practice
```

then I add the folder I want to using:

```
git add FolderName
```

then I use

```
git commit -m 'adding new folder'
```

I got this message after:

```
On branch practice
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

so I type the command:

```
git push origin practice
```

everything in the master branch will be copied in the new branch. so any suggestion if I want to create new branch and add only one folder not everything.

Comment: If the folder was empty git won't recognize it as a change in the repository.

Comment: no the folder got some java classes on it and it's already being pushed to the main branch the master

Comment: but I want to push it on different branch alone

Comment: For example in my main branch the master I have folderone , foldertwo , folderthree. I want to create new branch and add on it only foldertwo

Comment: Please update your question. Do not hide important clarifications into comments.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write there are two cases:

Either `FolderName` is empty: In this case git found no new files and therefore says "nothing to commit".

Or `FolderName` was already present in your main branch. In this case you tried to add files that git already knew about. - No changes -> no commit.

Your comment sounds like you actually want to *delete* folders: You already have folderone, foldertwo and folderthree and want to delete folderone and folderthree to end up with only foldertwo. - However that does not match the intension of your question.

Most probably the answer is: You don't have to add the folder. It is already present in the branch, like any other files of the main branch.

You can also use `git ls-files` to list all files git knows about.

Comment: Nope I do have two branches the master and another one. In the master I do have all the folders. I want to copy one of these folder in another branch so I want to end up with two branches one with all the folders and another one with only one folder which is not empty and which is already existing in the main branch

Comment: The idea behind it is I want the main branch to be as backup and the unstable code or unfinished I want to put it in different branch. but as I mentioned earlier every time I push one folder to the new branch I end up having all the folders which in my master branch in the another branch

Comment: Just to mention I don't want to delete anything

Comment: If you type `git branch practice` git will create a new branch which already contains all the files of the main branch. - If you want less you need to delete everything you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have folder A in branch master, you want to add folder A to branch practice.

> git checkout practice
>
> git checkout master -- A/*
>
> git add A
>
> git commit -m "Add folder A"

If the commit sha1 code you add A folder in branch master is 123456, it became more easy.

> git checkout practice
>
> git cherry-pick 123456

Comment: nice answer, think this is the last time I need to checkout howToCreateANewBranch